# FOP fails to generate pdf for certain URLS

Tags: xml, bash, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have an issue with generating pdf files using the apache fop tool from url based data, whenever there are certain characters or keywords such as utm or rel as the below given url

https://www.youtube.com/embed/1mDT-x2XnEg?autoplay=1&rel=0&feature=oembed&enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque

I get the following error

```
SEVERE: Exception
org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException: The reference to entity "rel" must end with the ';' delimiter.
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: The reference to entity "rel" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

My XML DATA FILE - mytest.xml contains:

```
<url>https://www.youtube.com/embed/1mDT-x2XnEg?autoplay=1&rel=0&feature=oembed&enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque</url>
```

My XSL TEMPLATE FILE - mytest.xsl contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root>
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4-portrait"
              page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21.0cm" margin="2cm">
          <fo:region-body/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4-portrait">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <fo:block>
            Testing URLS: <xsl:value-of select="url"/>!
          </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Tested on Commandline
FOP Version 2.2 on kali linux and opensuse linux 42.3

```
myvar=mytest && /opt/fop-2.2/fop/fop  -r -v -xml $myvar.xml -xsl $myvar.xsl -pdf $myvar.pdf
```

I have tried adding quotes around the URL, but to no effect. Fop seems to be interpreting the urls word by word or so it seems.

I tried another file using basiclink tag in template - mytest.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root>
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4-portrait"
              page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21.0cm" margin="2cm">
          <fo:region-body/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4-portrait">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <fo:block>

            <fo:basic-link external-destination="url({url/@href})"  color="blue" text-decoration="underline">  <xsl:value-of select="url/@href"/> </fo:basic-link>
          </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

No luck, Still the same.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Escape `&` as `&amp;`.

Your problem isn't with FOP, it's with your XML syntax.  In XML, `&` is the start of an entity reference, so the XML parser (not FOP itself) is trying to evaluate `&rel` (the longest sequence after the `&` that's valid as an entity name) as an entity name and is not finding the `;` that is required to end the entity reference.

See https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-references.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved with the use of wrapping the urls with CDATA as shown below:-

```
<![CDATA[\"$url\"]]>
```

CDATA stands for Character Data. We use it to escape some characters which otherwise will be treated as a standard regular XML. The data inside this will not be parsed, else you will end up with errors as its gonna be  parsed as a standard regular XML.